# How should a local variable in a function be initialized?

Tags: c++

How should a local variable in a function be initialized?  For performance reasons should I do it like this?

```
Point2D point(1,2);
```

or like this?

```
Point2D point = Point2D(1,2);
```

Does it even matter?

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not matter. Both will result in a call to the same constructor.

Comment: Doesn't the second call the copy constructor?

Comment: @Paul : It can, but most compilers won't with optimizations enabled (see also 'copy elision'). This is fundamentally a difference between _direct-initialization_ and _copy-initialization_.

Comment: @ildjarn The fact that compilers 'fix' the issue with the code is besides the point. Without optimization on, the second version could be twice as slow as the first version and certainly not in any way C++ish. :)

Comment: @Paul : The second way is not idiomatic, no argument there. But, the OP's concern is about performance, so of course he's going to have optimization on.

Comment: @ildjarn:  What compiler are you using where you have observed this behavior?  Is it G++ or Microsoft C++?  If what you say is true, it sounds really bad because it means you can accidentally write code that behaves differently depending on what optimizations are turned on.  I want to try to reproduce this.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Copy-ellision is one of the exception granted by the standard, where compilers are allowed to optimize away side-effects. That is why you should never rely on side-effects in a copy-constructor.

Comment: @Bjorn: Forget side effects, if you just happen to have a bug in your copy constructor that doesn't fully copy the state of your object, your code might behave very differently in Debug mode than it does in Release (optimized) mode.  That's scary.

Comment: If this thing is true, it's so scary that it would make a good argument for ALWAYS using the OP's first method.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: In the scenario you describe your code would have an error in Debug-mode, but run fine in release. That is not so scary.

Comment: @David : You'd have a harder time finding a compiler that _doesn't_ implement copy-elision than one that does.

Comment: @ildjarn:  Ok.  I found that MinGW's G++ does do copy elision, but it doesn't seem to depend on the optimization level, at least in my tests.  What compiler are you using where it depends on the optimization level?

Answer (score 4):

You should do it the first way because if you do it the second way I believe the compiler does something more complicated than necessary.  I think it creates a temporary object to represent the right-hand side, then uses the copy constructor to copy values to the object on the left hand side.

I might be wrong about this, so check your assembly listing.

Comment: I believe that the compiler will invoke the copy constructor using the temporary object, as opposed to calling the assignment operator.  I think the difference in terms of performance would just be the overhead of creating the temporary object which I would think would be insignificant in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer, changing "= operator" to "copy constructor".

Comment: In unoptimized mode, there will probably be a copy-ctor call. In optimized mode, probably not.

Comment: @Macke: What compiler are you using where you have observed this behavior? If what you say is true, it sounds really bad because it means you can accidentally write code that behaves differently depending on what optimizations are turned on.  I want to try to reproduce this.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Note the word 'probably'. OTOH, it's well known that copy-elison may take place, and yes, that could behave differently. But this is specified in the standard as conforming behaviour, as it does not affect the "percieved" result of the program (i.e. one less copy). If you print sometihng in each ctor you will see when this happens. This is very similar to the RVO/NVRO copy-elisions that skip copy-ctor when returning an object by value.

Answer (score 2):

The first one only calls the constructor while the second first calls the constructor and then copies it to `point`. Thus you should use the first one because it doesn't initiate a copy operation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does matter. The first version, `Point2D point(1,2)` will call the constructor, while the second, `Point2D point = Point2D(1,2)` will first create a new `Point2D` (the one to the right) and then will call the copy constructor to actually create `point`. As you can see, this is a big difference between C++ and Java or C#.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time return-value optimization will make those two options similar enough from a performance perspective (especially if you have a move-assignment operator defined)

There are other things to consider though.

If your type has an empty constructor, doing this is problematic:

```
Point2D p(); // instead of Point p;
```

This is known as the [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse).  It can be avoided by using the second form:

```
Point2D p = Point2D();
```

Or by using the *uniform initialization syntax* introduced in the latest standard:

```
Point2D p{};
```